# The counter for questions on Physics is working wrong

Tags: support, questions

Perhaps there are asked more questions on Physics Stack Exchange than the counter suggests.

As a little joke I asked the question 111,111. Now the counter is at 111,118 but after [my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376642/em-radiation-from-processes-without-photon-emission) 22 or so new questions have been asked:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it's not caching (the counter is now at 111,120), there's something else going on: [automatic cleanup of questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). Deleted questions do not count towards the total number of questions, and Roomba has been activated between your question (posted 11 hours ago) and the moment you checked the question counter, deleting 15 low quality questions. A ♦ moderator or user with [>10k reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) will be able to verify this by looking at the Recently deleted questions in the [moderator tools](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today).

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/775470/total-number-of-questions-deleted-ones-included) shows that (up till last Sunday morning) over 150,000 questions had been asked on Physics Stack Exchange, but more than 40,000 have already been deleted (mostly because they're low quality).

Comment: Simple check the number of questions after mine and compare with the counter. (I’m sometimes surprised the way specialists are working ;-)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler that's how I came up with the 15. Which 15 those are, is hard to determine unless you have privileges on Physics.SE.

Comment: Confirming this is a thing: as of now the "recently deleted" page shows twenty-five deleted questions in the past 24 hours.